# calling code in a new thread

Tags: c++

Using Visual C++ 32-bit, I have a function that looks like this:

```
void CastTestSpell(byte *packet, int length)
{
    ServerSend(packet, length);
}
```

I want to send the function call `ServerSend(packet, length);` in a new thread to break away from the current thread it's on so that it won't block it.

How can I do it?

Comment: What platform, what compiler, thirdparty libs ok? oh and what have you tried?

Comment: I'm not a C++ programmer and if I remember C well enough I believe you can "fork" a process?

Comment: I'm not using any 3rd party libs, But I will if I need to, I just want to do something like a thread delegate like you would in c#

Comment: @SergueiFedorov:  Thats a Unix/Linux thing.  There is no `fork` in Windows.

Comment: You want [beginthread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beginthread) or [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682516(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Spinning up a thread on every send is probably a bad idea fwiw.  I would take a look at boost::asio.  They have asynchronous sending facilities.  www.boost.org/libs/asio/

Comment: @JohnDibling good thing to know. Its about time I started catching up on C++; Windows 8 apps seem to be pushing it pretty hard, not a bad thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you manage the buffer objects somehow, you can just do

```
std::thread(&CastTestSpell, packet, length).detach();
```

(although I generally advise against the use of `detach()`: you probably want to get hold of the `std::thread` object and `join()` it at a strategic point).

The above code is using current standard C++ (C++ 2011). If it doesn't compile your C++ system is based on an outdated standard: Multi-threading support, including `std::thread` was added since the previous standard.

Comment: Best to note this is C++11.

Comment: C++ 2011 is the currently active standard. I'd think it can reasonably be assumed that people use the current standard as a basis. If you specifically target an outdated standard, ask for it! (yes, I'm aware there is not entirely compliant system available for C++ 2011 but neither is there for C++ 2003 and MSVC++ is far from compliant to C++ 1998, even)

Comment: do you mean something like this?  std::thread t = std::thread(&ServerSend, packet, length);
 t.detach();
 t.join();
  or do you see a problem with this?

Comment: @Dean if you are using vs2012 this is the easiest solution and the best

Comment: What is that saying about assuming?

Comment: could you please explain what you meant by "if im managing buffer objects somehow?"

Comment: @Dean: No, there is no need to name the object. The code creates a temporary object of type `std::thread` with a number of constructor parameters and calls the method `detach()` on this temporary object. Once the `detach()` completes the `std::thread` object (a handle to the thread) is destroyed since it isn't needed. The code runs in the detached thread.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Methinks you assume far too much.

Comment: @Dean: You pass a buffer of `byte` objects (`packet`) around. This needs to be hold on to while the thread is using it and it probably needs to be released at some point. For example, the memory should not be on the stack in the calling thread or be `delete`d by the calling thread until it is clear that the called thread is done using it. With the given signature I'd be suspicious about the buffer being guaranteed to be release. I'd pass around e.g. a `std::vector<byte>` which would release the memory when not being used anymore automatically...

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Windows API CreateThread(), if you want to do it the native Windows way.

However, if you call CastTestSpell() often, it's not a good idea to start a new thread every time, as the thread setup is low performance. In this case you need to use a thread pool (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686760%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)